# Google-maps-api Generate list of users proximity to master list of locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, proximity

I have a list of locations "A" and a list of users "B" that I need to generate a List from "C".

I need to be able to see which users in B are within say 1/4 mile of the locations in list "A" and dump that into a readable list (not a map).

Is there a relatively easy way to do this with the google-maps-api or am I barking up the wrong tree?

By the way all of the lists are static. Locations on "A" and "B' never change.

Sample info:
"A"  Holmes Detective Agency , 401 E South St, Jackson MS 39201
"B"  John Watson, 400 high st, Jackson MS 39201

Comment: what is sample inputs and expected outputs.please clarify

Comment: added a sample to the original

Comment: What is "C" then? How many locations do you need to compare? How do you store your locations (where, and do you have only addresses or coordinates?). Did you look for other questions here? There are many.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) API

```
origins      = Locations list A
destinations = Users list  B
```

You will have a response with something like this:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "user-1 address",
      "user-2 address"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ 
      "location-1",
      "location-2"
   ],

   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "4.2 km",
                  "value" : 4247
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "16 mins",
                  "value" : 968
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "11.7 km",
                  "value" : 11670
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "31 mins",
                  "value" : 1851
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Loop through the API response and compare `distance < x mile` 
and you will have your result.